# React Native clear function for inputs not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to clear the input field after data is submitted. I can update the text field on every submit however If I just press my submit button without typing into the text area it seem to just to be storing the old entry

```
state = {
    description: ""
  };

add() {
    this.setState({ saving: true });
    return TodoService.add(
      this.state.description
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this._txtDescription.clear();
        return res;
      })

<TextInput
    ref={(c) => (this._txtDescription = c)}
    label="Details"
    mode={"outlined"}
    theme={theme}
    multiline={true}
    numberOfLines={5}
    value={this.state.description}
    onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({ description })}
/>
<Button
            loading={this.state.saving}
            icon="upload"
            style={{ top: 15, marginTop: 40 }}
            mode={"outlined"}
            color={Color.primary}
            onPress={() =>
              this.state.title.length < 1
                ? alert("Please enter a title")
                : this.addInstant()
            }
          >
            Instant Message
          </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input value depends on the state, just reset the state instead of handling the ref value: `this.setState({description: ""})`.